# Different result COPY and ADD DockerFile

Tags: docker, filesystems

I have an issue with the instruction COPY in the docker file.
When using COPY to copy private and public keys into ~/.ssh/ the files are copied but when trying to SSH the key seems not to be used and the password is required

However, when I use the instruction ADD, the files are also there but this time ssh works without asking the password.

Is there a difference in the behaviour in terms of files results when using COPY or ADD?

Thank you in advance,

I am running OpenMPI in docker and I am setting up ssh between containers.
It works well when using ADD but not when using COPY.

Comment: `ADD` has some magic regarding decompression and accessing non local files compared to `COPY`. I could imagine there is also some magic regarding permissions. Maybe file permissions are different. ssh has some requirements on permissions of private keys (e.g. non readable by anyone except user)

Comment: You shouldn't copy ssh keys inside your images. Instead you should map volumes and let containers only access your local keys at runtime. Or generate keys per image...

Answer (score 1):

There are only two differences between [ADD](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/#add) and [COPY](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/#copy):

1. You can use a URL as the source argument to ADD, and Docker will fetch it; if you try to give a URL to COPY, it will try to resolve it as a relative path.
2. If you ADD a tar file, optionally compressed, ADD will unpack it into the destination; if you COPY a tar file, COPY will place it into the image unmodified.

[You should generally prefer COPY](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy) over ADD unless you explicitly want these behaviors.  If a file doesn't have a URL-format filename and isn't a tar file, COPY and ADD are identical.

It's unlikely COPY vs. ADD is causing this issue.  ssh has especially strict requirements on file ownership and permissions.  Docker is documented to copy files as owned by user 0, and I think it keeps the original file's permissions.  These might not match up with what ssh requires.

You should be especially careful when copying secrets like ssh keys into images (by which I mean, never do it).  Anyone who has the image can trivially extract the key back out, at which point they can freely ssh into your systems.  You don't want that to happen.

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
I checked the permissions and they are strictly the same.
I will keep investigating!

Regarding the fact copying SSH keys I understand the danger, in this case, it's just a shortcut to get the computation running, nothing in production.

Creating the SSH keys specifically per node will be complicated as for MPI to run I woud need to launch the master, create the ssh keys, extract the public key from the container, then launch the working nodes and finally copy the public key.
This requires some scripting :)